# solution of differential equation of the form f(x,y)/g(x,y)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If I'm given a differential equation of the form,

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}$

that apparently can't be homogenized, will the differential equation always be solvable?
For example, if I'm given the equation,

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x+2y-3}{2x+y-3}$

How am I supposed to solve it?

N.B. This isn't a homework question. I'm just curious whether this type of equations are solvable or not.

Comment: You could always try the substitution $y=v(x)x$ to find out.

Comment: Can't you bring it to the form of an exact differential equation? If so (and I think that's the case), it is solvable.

Comment: ^No, I'm asking about the ones which we can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}=\frac{ax+by+c}{k(ax+by)+d}=\frac{ax+by+c}{k(ax+by+C)}$$
with $C=\frac{d}{k}$ is solvable with the change of function :
$$Y(x)=ax+by+C \quad\to\quad y=\frac{Y-ax-C}{b}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm d Y}{\mathrm d x}-a=\frac{Y-C+c}{kY}=$$
$$\frac{\mathrm d Y}{\mathrm d x}=\frac{(1+ak)Y-C+c}{kY}$$
This is a separable ODE.
$$x=\int \frac{kY}{(1+ak)Y-C+c}=k\frac{(1+ak)Y+(c-C)\ln|(1+ak)Y-C+c|}{(1+ak)^2}+\text{ constant}$$
The inverse function $Y(x)$ involves the Lambert's W function.

Comment: ^This is what I wanted, but I urge you to add the general solution to the eqn. $dy/dx =(a_1x+b_1y+c_1)/(a_2x+b_2y+c_2)$ where $a_2x+b_2y$ is not equal to $k(a_1x+b_1y)$ Cause my question is a general one referring to both the cases. :)

Comment: I will not repeat in all details the well known general method. Already E.H.E. remind it : change $x=X+\alpha$ , $y=Y+\beta$ Solve the system of equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that the transformed equation be on the form $\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{a_1X+b_1Y}{a_2X+b_2Y}$. This is an homogeneous ODE . Change $Z=\frac{Y}{X}$. Consider the inverse function $X(Z)$. This leads to a linear ODE to be solved for $X(Z)$. Note that my previous answer was only to show how to solve the particular case $a_2x+b_2y=k(a_1x+b_1y)$ since the method for the general case was already given by E.H.E.

Answer (score 2):

let $x=X+a$ and $y=Y+b$
so
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{X+a+2(Y+b)-3}{2(X+a)+Y+b-3}$$
to make the D.E homogeneous, it must be
$$a+2b-3=0\tag 1$$
$$2a+b-3=0\tag2$$
solve them to get
$$a=b=1$$
so the new D.E becomes
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{X+2Y}{2X+Y}$$

Comment: Could you explain why do I need to equate $Eq. 1 & 2$ to be equal to 0 in order to make it homogeneous?

Comment: to cancel the constants from denominator and numerator

Comment: ^Got it. Now consider, that I'm given a differential equation such that equation 1 has same coefficients for a and b. And equation 2 also has same coefficients of a and b. (Geometrical Consequence: Plotting $a$ vs $b$ for both the equations we'll get 2 parallel straight lines i.e. no solutions) How am I supposed to tackle differential equations of this form?

Comment: For an example consider the differential equation                                         $ dy/dx = (x+y+1)/(2x+2y+3) $

Comment: @AnubhabDas  sorry, I dont know where is your problem

Comment: ^Please read the above comment.

Comment: for your example you can solve as: $$a+b+1=0\tag1$$ $$2a+2b+3=0\tag2$$

Comment: Take a look at these equations. They're unsolvable.

Comment: ok, wait me to check it

Comment: In this case the method does not work

Comment: @AnubhabDas the method does not work  for this case $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{ax+by+c}{k(ax+by)+d}$$